# Asp.Net-Mvc new area VS new project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a rather big project and I'm starting to write the administration panel for it. I'm asking myself is it better to create a new area for the administration or create a new project. I saw this "new project" approch in the NopCommerce source code.
Thanks

Comment: If the admin panel is designed to run on the same domain as the site, I would do it as an area, but if it would run on a different domain I would do it as another project.

Comment: Hey Ahmad, thanks for your answer. The admin panel will be at the same domain so your advise is to create it as an area. Do you have any idea why in nopcommerce they did it as a separate project?

Comment: I will also suggest to use area over new project. You will use your current identity provider and [Authorise(Role="Administrators")] attribute. In new project you will forced to reinvent a weel.

Comment: @webformer , sorry i have no idea. nopcommerce is a great framework and am sure they have their reasons, but I have never gone into it's code. In Orchard however they also use many projects, but the projects are of type "class libraries" not websites, there is only one project of type "web / mvc" that uses all other projects. They did it this way to make modules (projects -as each project represents a feature) easy to plug in and out.

Comment: One thing to consider: splitting into multiple projects can have the benefit of keeping your references more tidy, similar to the reason "onion architecture" (http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) uses multiple projects. For example, if the main project references  LibraryA, LibraryB, and LibraryC, but your admin area only references LibraryD (and not A, B, or C), you may want to consider separate projects. I'm not sure if this was a factor for nopcommerce.